# How to do CKAN custom development?

Tags: ckan

I am new to CKAN. I am not sure if any custom code that I need to add any new functionalities has to be implemented as CKAN extensions.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, writing a CKAN extension is the recommended way to add custom code to CKAN. We're currently working on a new tutorial for writing extensions, you can find the draft tutorial here: https://github.com/okfn/ckan/pull/943